# 301-Redirect with htaccess - change path

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I want to move some folders on my server and adjust the path with htaccess. Found a lot of questions like this on stackoverflow but I don't dare to transfer this answers.

I have a folder
www.bla.com/xinha/plugins/ImageManager/demo_images/

I want to move the folder and its whole content to
www.bla.com/images/xy/

How could I do this with htaccess?

Perhaps one could quickly help me out - thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place this rule in your root .htaccess:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/xinha/plugins/ImageManager/demo_images/(.+)$ /images/xy/$1
```

Comment: Thanks, anubhava - this works perfect! Is the ^ for "root" or does it just indicate the beginning of the path?!

Comment: `^` is actually start of path.

Comment: And the second path starts where the  ^-path started, right?

Comment: Sorry didn't understand your recent comment.

Comment: I mean: the ^ in the first path (to be replaced) "stores" where the path starts, in our example above e.g. www.abc.com/bla/ (continuing with /xinha/...). The second path (in our example /images/xy...) will then always start at the same point the first path started (in our example: abc.com/bla/)? (sorry ... maybe to complicated to explain in a short comment :-)

Comment: First part is matching this regex `^/xinha/plugins/ImageManager/demo_images/(.+)$` and capturing part in `( and )` in `$1`. Then in target URI it uses captured group i.e. `/images/xy/$1`